# Whether to sign a lease agreement that is poorly worded/too broad if landlord will not change it?

Tags: contract-law

I am looking at signing a lease on an apartment, but there are a few phrases that give me pause:

"Resident agrees that Resident is at all times responsible for the conduct and actions of all other persons regardless of any culpability or knowledge on Resident’s part."

I imagine that the *intent* is to say all other persons *party to this lease or guests thereof*, but there is no qualification like this actually in the lease.

The second phrase that I'm getting hung up on is this:

"To the greatest extent permitted by law, **Landlord shall not be liable to Resident**, even for negligent acts or omissions of Landlord or Landlord's agents or employees, **for any damage or injury**, whether to person or property, loss, or destruction to Resident's property, including but not limited to any damage or injury, whether to person or property, loss, or destruction of property **sustained by Resident from any cause** including but not limited to the causes and risks set forth herein."

This *seems* to me to exempt the landlord from responsibility, even in the event that he or she breaks into my apartment and shoots me, given that it is always *permitted by law* that a victim choose not to press charges. Is this correct?

Also, related to this, if the landlord is **not** willing to change the wording of the lease agreement, are these pretty standard things to see on a lease that I shouldn't worry about? (Maybe because they're not enforceable?)

Thanks very much

Comment: A similar part of my lease says (under the title Tenant Insurance): 

"Landlord shall not be liable to Tenant, Tenant’s Family, or Tenant’s invitees, licensees, and/or guests for damages not proximately caused by Landlord or landlord’s agents." I don't see anything written as strongly as the term in yours. The modern trend in the law is to assign landlords a general duty of reasonable care and that they will be held liable for injuries of tenants and guests resulting from landlord's ordinary negligence, but landlord needs prior notice and a reasonable opportunity to repair the defect.

Comment: @A.fm. Thanks, I may copy/paste that and request it as a rephrase. That is the same section in which this passage appears.

Comment: No problem. FYI, the rest of that section goes on to say he's not liable for Acts of God, strongly encourages me to purchase tenant's insurance, and that I and my possessions are not covered by the Landlord's insurance. Also FYI, in case you're not familiar but want to know what you'd be requesting from the landlord by modifying that clause with the above term, proximate cause is typically determined with a "but for" analysis. So if I would not have had a broken foot, "but for" the landlord negligently installing a set of cabinets, he can be found liable.

Comment: To expand off of @A.fm.'s comment, you are ignoring perhaps the most important piece of the term: "To the greatest extent permitted by law". The law requires them to be liable in a lot of situations where they simply cannot waive their liability. The term is meant to waive liability in all cases where they are *allowed* to do so.

Comment: @animuson ok that is part of what I was wondering. There is a bit later on though that is not about the landlord waiving liability, but rather says: "To the greatest extent permitted by law, Resident agrees to hold Landlord harmless and to indemnify Landlord against and from any lawsuit, loss, cost, expense, damage, or claim including attorneys' fees and costs resulting from any injury, whether to property or to person, whether to Resident, Resident’s family, occupants, guests, invitees, or any person entering the Premises or the community of which the Premises is a part."

Comment: @animuson are there also situations wherein the victim is not permitted by law to hold the perpetrator of an act harmless? Aka required to press charges?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your part about required to press charges. The only times I can think of when a victim is not allowed to hold someone accountable is if the statute of limitations (basically a timeframe within which you must sue) has passed or if it is a negligence claim and you're in a contributory negligence jurisdiction and you contributed to the reason or action that led to your injury. Back in the day, landlords had no duty to repair or maintain properties. Today, not the case anymore.

Comment: @A.fm. But when are they allowed to hold someone NOT accountable? The point is that this passage seems to say that I will be bound to hold the landlord NOT accountable in all cases where that is permitted by law. (Which as far as my knowledge goes is ALL cases.)

Comment: It is saying that in any way the law allows the landlord to escape liability, he will. Also that the tenant is waiving any optional rights to that effect. However, there are certain rights that are unwaivable, such as the warranty of habitability which says landlord must ensure heat and water (bare necessities) are operable. If you're that much of a masochist that you don't want any action taken in that respect, then you just shut your mouth, don't call code enforcement, and shiver away your winter.

Comment: Does anyone have any comments about the first part?

Comment: Your getting caught up in the semantics of whether you technically could or could not bring a complaint against him. The premise of clauses worded in that way, however, presume the tenant (or whoever the passage is talking about) is a rational actor making decisions in his or her best interest.

Comment: @A.fm.  My question is about whether I would be signing away my right to bring a complaint against the landlord by signing this. Are you saying the answer is no?

Comment: Also, if a criminal matter arose, it would be out of your hands whether or not the landlord was charged.

Comment: From what you've provided, I think it is saying you are signing away your ability to go after the landlord in any of the methods that are waivable. You are waiving your waivable rights. It cannot apply to certain rights because some rights you have are unwaivable. Also, courts often find contracts of this nature unconscionable and the clause that signs your rights away (if that is what it indeed does do) would be rendered void.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: That's not expert advice, by the way, but my personal, non-legal-advice-giving opinion would be to urge the landlord to modify terms to what we discussed above. Despite the unconscionable safeguard, you don't want to even have to deal with all of that. Local attorney consultation would be valuable, too, since laws can be different across jurisdictions.

Comment: The first part includes visitors, not just people on the lease. If you have a friend visiting who's an illegal drug user and the friend is carrying/ingests/sells/etc in the property, the owner can kick you out for allowing it to happen.